# ASP.NET "access is denied" error accessing UNC path

Tags: asp.net, windows, authorization

Correction added below: the code in question is not part of an IIS 7 Application (no app pool).

I have an IIS virtual directory that includes an aspx page with the following code:

```
System.Net.WebRequest wr = System.Net.WebRequest.Create( @"file://unc-share/directory/file.pdf" );
wr.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
WebResponse response = wr.GetResponse();
```

When GetResponse() is invoked, I get an "Access to the path '\unc-share\directory\file.pdf' is denied." error.

I have the app configured for Integrated Windows Authentication (all other authentication types are disabled), ASP.NET Impersonation is Enabled.

I have been able to verify that ASP.NET impersonation is using the same identity as the Windows domain account I am using to access the site.  The UNC share where the file resides, which is a separate Windows system that does not host a web server, is set up with "Full Control" privileges for this same account.

I have also tried accessing the file using a FileStream instance, with the same results.

Been digging around on this issue on this site and others, but haven't found any suggestions that match what I'm trying to do, nor which solve the problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Access the path like this:

```
System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"\\uncshare\directory\file.pdf");
```

The important part of this snippet is the formatting of the path and the absence of the WebRequest.  There are several methods you could use to open the file.  I use `File.ReadAllText` as an example, but you could just as easily open the file using a FileStream.

There shouldn't be a need to use a WebRequest, since the file is not behind a web server.

Comment: To clarify: the file could be a text file, but it will usually not be - pdf, docx, various other non-text formats.  Also, the file is on a remote system, accessed via UNC path.  At any rate, what I ultimately need out of this is a stream to hand off to a different app, not the contents of the file.  And, even with text files, ReadAllText throws the same error.

Comment: @hoobajoob, I used `ReadAllText` as an example.  You could use `ReadAllBytes` for binary files or open the file using a reader, for example.  I suppose it doesn't matter though, since you are getting the same error.  Are you able to access the UNC path from the server by typing it into the Start > Run dialog?

Comment: yes, the UNC paths that I have tested with are accessible from the server.

Comment: fwiw: WebRequest.Create() returns a FileWebRequest() instance when provided with a file:// uri, which is the case in this implementation.  This usage is apparently to support an abstraction that permits retrieving content transparently across the access medium (see [here](http://etutorials.org/Programming/C+in+a+nutshell+tutorial/Part+IV+API+Quick+Reference/Chapter+33.+System.Net/FileWebRequest/) ).In the specific usage where I found this code snippet, I think the input will always end up being a path

Comment: fwiw continued: at any rate, there doesn't appear to be a good reason why this method shouldn't work in principle.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the formatting is correct. However, Microsoft specifically writes

> The FileWebRequest class relies on the File class for error handling and code access security.

And about the Credentials property..

> **Credentials**
> Gets or sets the credentials that are associated with this request. *This property is reserved for future use*.

In practice it means, the underlying components for file sharing is based on the System.IO classes. So, when passing credentials, you are depending on Windows-based authentication.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.filewebrequest?view=net-8.0